# How to find the difference between two values in same column different rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, window-functions

I need to create a query to define changes in price for different version .
For example this is the table :

```
id | price | date| version 
1  | 10    |2020-06-01| 1
1  | 15    |2020-06-12| 2
2  | 4     |2020-06-03| 1
2  | 5     |2020-06-04| 2
2  | 5.5   |2020-06-10| 3
```

I started to create one query like this :

```
select t1.price - t2.price from product_price_version t1, product_price_version t2 
where t1.version = t2.version - 1
```

I need to have as results :

```
id | price | date| version | difference 
1  | 10    |2020-06-01| 1  | 0
1  | 16    |2020-06-12| 2  | 6
2  | 4     |2020-06-03| 1  | 0
2  | 5     |2020-06-04| 2  | 1
2  | 5.5   |2020-06-10| 3  | 1.5
```

in the end to add a filter and to show values where difference is greater than 5

Comment: You can use lag() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select
    t.*,
    price - lag(price, 1, price) over(partition by id order by version) diff
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, you can self-join or use a correlated subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    t.price - coalesce(t1.price, t.price) diff
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.version = t.version - 1
```

Comment: mysql error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by id order by version) diff

Comment: @Botalbania: your version of MySQL does not support window functions. You can use the second query instead.

Comment: it work with the second , how can i add as condition where t.price - coalesce(t1.price, t.price) >100 and last version of product , can you help me please ?

Comment: @Botalbania: just add a `where` clause: `where t.price - coalesce(t1.price, t.price) > 5`